# How can I get the name of a class through a reference to an instance of a subclass?

Tags: c#

How can I get the name of a class through a reference to an instance of a subclass?

For example,

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public void ClassName()
    {
        // How can I get the name of the base class "BaseClass" here, without having to hardcode "BaseClass"?
        Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name); 
    }
}

public class SubClass: BaseClass
{
    public void ClassName()
    {
        base.ClassName();
        Console.WriteLine(this.GetType().Name);
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SubClass MyObject = new SubClass();
    MyObject.ClassName();
}
```

The output is

```
SubClass
SubClass
```

But I want

```
BaseClass
SubClass
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Generic Method

Probably the cleanest approach:

```
public static class TypeHelperExtensions
{
    public static string GetTypeName<T>(this T Object)
    {
        return typeof(T).Name;
    }
}
```

And then:

```
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public virtual void ClassName()
        {
            // How can I get the name of the base class "BaseClass" here, without having to hardcode "BaseClass"?
            Console.WriteLine(this.GetTypeName()); 
        }
    }

    public class SubClass: BaseClass
    {
        public override void ClassName()
        {
            base.ClassName();
            Console.WriteLine(this.GetTypeName()); 
        }
    }
```

### nameof()

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void ClassName()
    {
        // How can I get the name of the base class "BaseClass" here, without having to hardcode "BaseClass"?
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(BaseClass)); 
    }
}

public class SubClass: BaseClass
{
    public override void ClassName()
    {
        base.ClassName();
        Console.WriteLine(nameof(SubClass));
    }
}
```

### Reflection

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void ClassName()
    {
        // If you know you will have only one parent
        var b = type.BaseType.Name
    }
}
```

if you don't know the structure you may have to do something like the following:

```
    private bool _ignoreMe;

    public void ClassName()
    {
        var b = this.GetType().GetField(nameof(_ignoreMe), BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).DeclaringType;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. `nameof(BaseClass)`  hardcodes `BaseClass`. I want the code to be the same in any class, not just in `BaseClass`, so prefer no hardcoding.